# How to pass values to the function on click event, in polymer-3.x?

Tags: polymer-3.x

I am looping an array of objects. each object has name and address for example. On click event, i want to send the clicked name to the function.
Example: `on-click="myFunc('[[item.name]]')"`

My current code:

```
static get template() {
  ...
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]">
      <a name="[[item.name]]" on-click="myFunc">[[item.name]]</a>
  </template>
}

myFunc(name) {
  console.log('Clicked name is ', name);
}
```

**How to get the clicked name in the function `myFunc` ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [API](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/templates):

> When you add a declarative event handler inside the dom-repeat
>   template, the repeater adds a model property to each event sent to the
>   listener. The model object contains the scope data used to generate
>   the template instance, so the item data is model.item

Using that information, you can access your item using

```
myFunc(event) {
  const name = event.model.item.name;
  console.log('Clicked name is', name);
}
```